# Bad Request MVC HttpPost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0

I have the following cshtml file.

```
   @model Models.AuthorizeUser
   @{
   ViewBag.Title = "Authorize";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

<div class="container">
    <div class="card card-container">
        <img class="profile-img-card" src="~/Content/images/rblogo_reverse-pms348_000.gif" />
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <form method="POST">
        <p>Hello, @Model.Name</p>
        <p>A third party application want to do the following on your behalf:</p>
        <ul>

            @foreach (var scope in Model.Scopes)
            {

                <li>@scope.ScopeDescription</li>
            }
        </ul>
            <div class ="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-signin" name="submit" type="submit" value="authorize">Grant</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-signin btn-small-text" name="submit" type="submit" value="logout">Sign in as different user</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have my controller file as follows:

```
public class OAuthController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Authorize()
    {
        logger.Trace("Authorize method entered");
        AuthorizeUser authorizeUser;
               ......
        return View(authorizeUser);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Authorize(AuthorizeUser authorizeUser, string submit)
    {
        logger.Trace("Authorize with object");
        if (Response.StatusCode != 200)
        {
            logger.Trace("status code " + Response.StatusCode);
            logger.Trace("status description " + Response.StatusDescription);
            return View("AuthorizeError");
        }
          ..............
    }
```

When the form is displayed, the info is displayed correctly. After I click Grant button, I got Response.StatusCode == 400. Both authorizeUser and submit are null. I am expecting StatuCode == 200 with values of authrizeUser and submit.

Comment: Is there some javascript is sending this information because you don't have any form fields that would actually get POST'ed in your code.

Comment: The original code was not mine. There is no javascript code.  I want to send Models.AuthorizeUser  to the controller method.

Comment: A form only posts back the name/value pairs of its successful form controls (`<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`). You don't have any form controls for the properties of your `AuthorizeUser` model

Comment: AuthorizeUser was populated by a different from. The fields are displayed here. What could cause Response.StatusCode = 400?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Html.BeginForm()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#Anchor_5)?

Instead of using `<form method="POST">` you could use `Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller")`

Comment: The original code used html.BeginForm(). It didn't work. So I changed to <form method="POST">.

Comment: Where exactly do you populate the model?

Comment: I created OAuthServer following the example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server.  The model is define as public class AuthorizeUser
 {

  public AuthorizeUser()
  {
   Scopes = new List<Scope>();
  }


  public string Name { get; set; }

  public List<Scope> Scopes { get; set; }

  public bool AccessGranted { get; set; }

 }